# Second SQL Statement not executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a player as well as give him a few stats.

But the problem is 1. Doesn't add the stats, 2. I need the gamer added first so I can get the gamerId returned.

```
    $sqlPlayer = "INSERT INTO players (`gender`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES('$gender','$username','$email','$password')";
    echo $sqlPlayer."</br>";

    if ($db->query($sqlPlayer))
    {
        echo "Player added. </br>";

        $GamerId = $db -> lastInsertId();
        echo "Gamer id added:".$GamerId." </br>";

        $_SESSION['GamerId'] = $GamerId;
        echo "Gamer session added:".$_SESSION['GamerId']." </br>";

        $sqlStats = "INSERT INTO stats (`GamerId`,`Health`,`Stamina`,`Food`,`Coins`,`SuperCoin`) VALUES(`$GamerId`,`100`,`250`,`4`,`500`,`0`)";
        echo $sqlStats."</br>";

        if ($db->query($sqlStats))
        {
            echo "Stats for player added.</br>";
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

As seen above I've added a few echo's to see what works and what doesn't to have a visual on what is happening.

So far I always get:

```
INSERT INTO players (`gender`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES('*gender*','*username*','*email*','*password*')

Player added.

Gamer id added:25 

Gamer session added:25

INSERT INTO stats (`GamerId`,`Health`,`Stamina`,`Food`,`Coins`,`SuperCoin`) VALUES(`7`,`100`,`250`,`4`,`500`,`0`)
```

`Health`,`Stamina`,`Food`,`Coins`,`SuperCoin` have a standard value in the database and because of this I've also tried:

```
INSERT INTO stats (`GamerId`,`Health`,`Stamina`,`Food`,`Coins`,`SuperCoin`) VALUES(`25`,` `,` `,` `,` `,` `)

INSERT INTO stats (`GamerId`) VALUES(`25`)
```

Comment: Wrap off backtick from values . Better use prepare statement!!

Comment: try semicolon after every query

Comment: Add an answer saty, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Saty pointed out, the `VALUES` clause contains backticks instead of apostrophes. So, you can do this:

```
    $sqlStats = "INSERT INTO stats (`GamerId`,`Health`,`Stamina`,`Food`,`Coins`,`SuperCoin`) VALUES('$GamerId','100','250','4','500','0')";
                                                                                                    ^^^      ^^^
```

Depending on your db schema, using numbers for numeric fields might be useful too. I.e.:

```
         VALUES(..., 500, ...)
    No apostrophes: ^^^^^^
```